# Get rid of "The Wi-Fi network ... could not be joined." message

Tags: network, wifi

How can I get rid of this message?

[image: Message]

I've tried clicking both: "Cancel" and "Run Diagnostics" buttons. I've also tried to turn off and back on the Wi-fi. I **don't** want to restart my mac as there are some important processes running.

I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina) - macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Comment: To clarify, clicking both "Cancel" and "Run Diagnostics" do nothing?

Comment: @Jake3231 Indeed, nothing happens when I click either of them. Perhaps I could close the process from _Activity Monitor_ but I kinda don't know how the process behind that windows is called ...

Comment: I thought about the same thing, but I'm not sure what that process would be called either. If someone knows the correct process, that would be good.

Comment: Have you tried turning WiFi off, and turning bluetooth off both on the mac and the ios device?

Comment: @Cajuu', How did you manage to get that to hang?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128340/cannot-join-wifi-network-please-move-closer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Go to Spotlight (magnifying glass in top corner) / Finder > Activity Monitor
2. Search for SystemUIServer in CPU tab using the search bar located at top right corner
3. Force quit it

Comment: You can also try `killall SystemUIServer` in Terminal.

Answer (score 11):

try connecting after removing any USB device connected. It worked for me.

Comment: I am like, "WTF"? It worked, I would ask how, but the better question is WHY?

Answer (score 3):

I followed many tips provided thru various Apple / Mac blogs. I did all of the obvious and logical tips, router, turn-off, turn-on WiFi and my MacBook Air wouldn't connect to my wireless network, or via a Bluetooth hotspot from my phone. It would connect on Bluetooth, even sending a pairing request only to disconnect. I could not load my Network name when choosing a network

So, I connected my iPhone (Did have an active connection to my wireless network) via USB as an option in my Network on the Mac. Then went to: System Preferences > Network. Under location, I went to Edit Location, created a location named "Untitled". Instead of Automatic, I chose "Untitled." I instantly received a password request for my network. I'm now connected and Location has defaulted to Automatic.Removed the iPhone connection and I'm up and running. It wasn't pretty, but it worked.

Comment: Or my other favorite: connect via phone to the wifi, then connect via bluetooth to the phone.  Hacky but sometimes works :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > Network > Advanced...

Select the Wi-Fi tab and you will see the list of Preferred Networks. Select the offending Wi-Fi network from the list, and click the minus button to remove it.

Now, when you click Cancel on that pop-up it shouldn't reappear.

Comment: Doesn't look like it works. The problem still persists

Comment: This might be a little overkill, but ... Go to System Preferences > Network. Find that network in the list and then uncheck "Automatically join this network". Then, turn off your Wi-Fi. Next, go to Advanced... uncheck "Remember networks this computer has joined", and then select that network and click the minus button. Then, turn on your Wi-Fi again.